# Is the __init__.py file a module?

Tags: python

Is  `__init__.py` file is a module ? I am learning python and come across packages and modules and i have one doubt that weather `__init__.py` file can be consider as module Since every python file is module so can we consider `__init__.py` as module ?

Comment: I would say so. Why are you asking?

Comment: Actually i have confusion regarding this.

Comment: so if i consider this as module so can i import this ??

Comment: It's actually an interesting question, but knowing whether `__init__.py` is a module has exactly 0 practical benefits. It really doesn't matter one bit.

Comment: Well, did you try?

Comment: I'd consider the directory where `__init__.py` is to be the module. As long as it contains an `__init__.py` file it can be imported.

Comment: @Djib2011: I would think a directory that contains an `__init__.py` file could not be considered a module. It's a *package*, and as such it can be imported, but `import package` is basically syntactic sugar for `import package.__init__ as package`, right?

Comment: @DanielPryden True. I meant that, the way I see it, the `__init__.py` is meant to be a handle for a package and not to be used individually.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-module) a module is

> An object that serves as an organizational unit of Python code. Modules have a namespace containing arbitrary Python objects. Modules are loaded into Python by the process of importing.

Which (imho) borders on gibberish for saying "`module` objects or files with Python code."

Since even an empty `__init__.py` file contains valid Python code, and you can import it via `import __init__`, it would technically be considered a module.
I don't know how this knowledge could be useful.